# Install a python module from OpenWrt makefile

Tags: python, makefile, embedded-linux, openwrt

I need to write an openWrt Makefile which installs a module into python, using setuptools, i.e. calls:
python setup.py install

I have setup.py file in my package.

Failed to find the answer in OpenWrt package build referrence

I hope there's some infra structure for setuptools in OpenWrt? I suppose I have to include some .mk file 
$(call include_mk, python-package.mk)?

and then call some target from it?

Will appreciate any sample Makefile/manual

Comment: Will you be able to share your steps on how to add custom python module to OpenWrt build? I want to do that too... I have my module ready but no idea how and what to do in OpenWRT builder/ config files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you talking about your own private python module or a publicly available one?
Here's an example Makefile for the 'idna' library, which I use.

```
include $(TOPDIR)/rules.mk

PKG_NAME:=idna
PKG_VERSION:=2.6
PKG_RELEASE:=1
PKG_SOURCE:=idna-2.6.tar.gz
PKG_SOURCE_URL:=https://pypi.python.org/packages/f4/bd/0467d62790828c23c47fc1dfa1b1f052b24efdf5290f071c7a91d0d82fd3/
PKG_BUILD_DIR:=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(PKG_NAME)-$(PKG_VERSION)/

#PKG_BUILD_DEPENDS:=python-setuptools 

include $(INCLUDE_DIR)/package.mk
$(call include_mk, python-package.mk)

define Package/idna
    SECTION:=lang-python
    CATEGORY:=Languages
    SUBMENU:=Python
    TITLE:=idna
    URL:=https://pypi.python.org/pypi/idna
    DEPENDS:=+python
endef

define Package/idna/description
    Internationalized Domain Names in Applications (IDNA)
endef

define Build/Compile
    $(call Build/Compile/PyMod,., \
        install --prefix="/usr" --root="$(PKG_INSTALL_DIR)" \
    )
endef

define Build/InstallDev
    $(INSTALL_DIR) $(STAGING_DIR)$(PYTHON_PKG_DIR)
    $(CP) \
        $(PKG_INSTALL_DIR)$(PYTHON_PKG_DIR)/* \
        $(STAGING_DIR)$(PYTHON_PKG_DIR)/
    [ ! -e $(PKG_INSTALL_DIR)/usr/include ] || $(CP) \
        $(PKG_INSTALL_DIR)/usr/include/* \
        $(STAGING_DIR)/usr/include/
endef

define Package/idna/install
    $(INSTALL_DIR) $(1)$(PYTHON_PKG_DIR)/
    $(CP) \
        $(PKG_INSTALL_DIR)$(PYTHON_PKG_DIR)/* \
        $(1)$(PYTHON_PKG_DIR)/
endef

$(eval $(call BuildPackage,idna))
```

If you have your own package/source, then host it somewhere like gitlab and use that as your source url etc... something like this..

```
PKG_NAME:=myPackage
PKG_VERSION:=1.0
PKG_RELEASE=$(PKG_SOURCE_VERSION)

PKG_SOURCE_PROTO:=git
PKG_SOURCE_URL:=git@gitlab.com:yourprofile/myPackage.git
PKG_SOURCE_SUBDIR:=$(PKG_NAME)-$(PKG_VERSION)
PKG_SOURCE_VERSION:=d65acd7649939505ebedd445f301c46b52616532
PKG_SOURCE:=$(PKG_NAME)-$(PKG_VERSION)-$(PKG_SOURCE_VERSION).tar.gz
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's what I need. And yes, it's a private module

Comment: Where to put this file and sources?